# Как для каждого элемента массива сделать изменение счетчика отдельно при нажатии на кнопку в ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

При нажатии кнопки + или - значения счетчика меняются одновременно. Как сделать, чтобы они менялись каждый отдельно?

[image: ингредиенты]

Значения chiken rice baobab берутся из массива объектов

```
[
      {
        id: 'd75f762a-eadd-49be-8918-ed0daa8dd024',
        name: 'Chicken tikka masala',
        price: 12,
        ingredients: ['chicken', 'rice', 'baobab'],
      }
]
```

Код компонента Ingredient:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '../Button/Button';

export const Ingredient = ({ ingredient }) => {
  console.log(ingredient);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Ingredients:</h3>
      <ul>
        {ingredient.ingredients.map((item) => (
          <li>
            <Button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</Button>
            {count}
            <Button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</Button>
            {item}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '../Button/Button';

export const Ingredient = ({ ingredient }) => {
  const count, setCount = useState({chicken: 1, rice:1, baobab: 1});

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Ingredients:</h3>
      <ul>
        {ingredient.ingredients.map((item) => (
          <li>
            <Button onClick={() => setCount({...count,[item]:count[item]--})}>-</Button>
            {count[item]}
            <Button onClick={() => setCount({...count,[item]:count[item]++})}>+</Button>
            {item}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: useState должен остаться, в вашем варианте его нет. Как это реализовать с хуком? Спасибо.

Comment: внес изменения в код

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так...
Но при таком варианте материнский элемент не узнает значение счетчиков для его элементов.

```js
const Button = ({onClick, children}) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>
  );
}

const Item = ({item}) => {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1);

    return (
      <li>
        <Button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}> - </Button>
        {count}
        <Button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}> + </Button>
        {item}
      </li>
    )
}

const Ingredient = ({ingredient}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3> Ingredients: </h3>
      <ul>
        {ingredient.ingredients.map((item) => <Item key={item} item={item}/>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
        
const App = props => {
  const o = {
    id: 'd75f762a-eadd-49be-8918-ed0daa8dd024',
    name: 'Chicken tikka masala',
    price: 12,
    ingredients: ['chicken', 'rice', 'baobab'],
  }
  
  return (
    <Ingredient ingredient = {o}/>
  )
}


const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer); root.render( < App / > );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

P.S.
Форматирование кода в песочнице оставляет желать лучшего. :(

Comment: Ваш вариант похож на правду, попытаюсь прикрутить его к своему проекту. Пытаюсь понять, что в моем коде не так. Получается, нужно компонент Button отрисовать в родителе, а у меня всё в одном месте.

Comment: "Форматирование кода в песочнице оставляет желать лучшего" - ну так не делайте его тогда :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, я про это и написал в своем ответе. Для полной функциональности ТС предоставил мало информации.

Comment: @ghost3ds, компоненты удобнее делать вообще отдельно в разных папках или файлах, а потом подключать по мере надобности.

Comment: @ksa Ваша правда, ночью не увидел это, комментарий по поводу этого удалю (этот тоже, чуть позже)